# C++ templates with multiple typenames

Tags: c++, arrays, function, templates

I'm learning about a technique used to find the number of elements in an array (so that I can hopefully starting writing sorting algorithms without requiring the length of the array to be passed with the array as a parameter) but in the tutorial, this line appears as the template declaration:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
```

I honestly didn't know you could declare multiple typenames in one template declaration, but furthermore what does "size_t N" do? is this a variable declaration inside of a template declaration as well?

Comment: No size_t means that you're creating a template using an integer value of type size_t, if you are using compile time arrays, (usually for small N) this can help you.

You have to understand that `typename T` means that T is a placeholder for a generic type in the template.

Comment: size_t is an unsigned type used to contain a size of some kind such as the size of a buffer in number of bytes or number of characters.

Comment: Note there's [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent). These might help you as well with the number of elements in an array.

Comment: @DyP, Interesting, I only saw `std::extent` quite a while ago and forgot about it.

Comment: @chris Though I don't understand why they haven't provided a constexpr function to deduce the length.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, True, it's not something you keep at the front of your mind as being useful. I, if I didn't use `std::array` so much, would have used the OP's example of a size template parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`size_t` is a type that resembles `unsigned int`. Having it in the template parameter just means that you pass a `size_t`, not a type. `N` probably represents the size of an array, which is an unsigned value. For example:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void zeroArray(T (&arr)[N]) {    //arr is a reference to an array 
    std::fill(arr, arr + N, 0);  //of N elements of type T
}

int main() {
    int arr[3];
    zeroArray<int, 3>(arr);
}
```

In the example, I could have said:

```
zeroArray(arr);
```

because both template arguments are deduced.

Comment: One note: If using C++11, `std::begin` and `std::end` work for arrays, so you can use those instead of `arr` and `arr + N`. You can make your own for C++03 as well.

Comment: I'm using fedora as the prime op system on my laptop, I'm honestly completely unaware what version of C++ i'm using (i'll google how to check it after posting this) but I do have a question. I constantly install every available update I can, are the c++ libraries updated for most linux systems in doing so?

Comment: @kjh, I'm not sure; I don't use Linux. One thing you can do to check your version is to print the value of `__cplusplus`, though. However, I remember GCC not updating that for a while. I know GCC 4.7.2 has it set properly.

Answer (score 2):

> what does "size_t N" do? is this a variable declaration inside of a template declaration as well?

Yep, basically.

Template arguments may be types or values of integer type. There are a few other things they can be, too (see `[C++11: 14.3.2/1]`) and I wouldn't call them "variables" *per se*, but...

Anyway, the values can be deduced just like types, too, so:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t array_size(const T (&)[N])
{
    return N;
}

int main()
{
   int  x[5];
   char y[10];
   std::string z[20];

   std::cout << array_size(x) << ',' << array_size(y) << ',' << array_size(z) << '\n';
}
```

Output: `5,10,20`.

Perfectly valid.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a variable (prvalue). And there are some more types you can use (I guess you know that, just for reference).

Comment: @DyP: Who's calling it a variable? And yes they're listed in `[C++11: 14.3.2/1]`. Just for reference.

Comment: The OP, and it might seem like you agree ("is this a variable declaration").

Comment: @DyP: Oh, oops. Sorry wasn't looking in the quote. OK well... yeah. :) Better now?